# How to know the server is down in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Is there any way to know if server is down or up in javascript?

I used `XMLHttpRequest` to post request, e.g.

```
request.open("GET", url, false);
```

This is in php :-

```
    <?php 
    if (fsockopen('www.sitepointforums.com', 80)){  
         echo('The server in online');  
        } else{  
        echo('The server in offline');  
      } 
        ?>
```

I want to be do same in javascript.
anyone suggest me something?

Comment: and what was wrong with that code?. Which issue you experienced?

Comment: XMLHttpRequest won't work cross-domain I think

Comment: sorry but it works for me

Comment: special privileges you have!

Comment: @user3627152 it works only when other domain allows cross-domain resquests

Comment: my issue is how to know server is down or up when i send request to it

Comment: the question itself is clear, but it is unclear what is exactly your attempted solution, there's no a complete example and we still don't know what is exactly the problem

Answer (score 0):

may be this helps

```
request.ontimeout = function () {
    console.error("Server is down");
};
request.timeout = 10000; // ms = 10sec
```